# Sending http request Google Vertex AI end point

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I've just deployed an ML model on Google vertex AI, it can make predictions using vertex AI web interface. But is it possible to send a request from a browser, for example, to this deployed model. Something like

```
http://myapp.cloud.google.com/input="features of an example"
```

and get the prediction as output.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can send using endpoint URL as.

```
https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/us-central1/endpoints/<ENDPOINT_ID>:predict
```

Data should be given as in POST parameter.

```
{
  "instances": 
    [1.4838871833555929,
 1.8659883497083019,
 2.234620276849616,
 1.0187816540094903,
 -2.530890710602246,
 -1.6046416850441676,
 -0.4651483719733302,
 -0.4952254087173721,
 0.774676376873553]
}
```

URL should be Region Based.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternatif you can use Bearer Token to get prediction

1. Install gcloud CLI.  [Reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)
2. Run `gcloud auth application-default login` and you must login your account
3. Run `gcloud auth print-access-token` to get the token

Now you can hit the endpoint by using cURL command or via Postman

```
curl \
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/ui/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/endpoints/${ENDPOINT_ID}:predict -d '{
  "instances": {
    "mimeType": "text/plain",
    "content": "YOUR_TEXT_CONTENT"
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Endpoint URL

Vertex AI document - guide - [Send an online prediction request](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-predictions-custom-models#send_an_online_prediction_request)

> HTTP method and URL:
>
> - LOCATION: The region where you are using Vertex AI.
> - PROJECT: Your project ID
> - ENDPOINT_ID: The ID for the endpoint.
>
> ```
> POST https://LOCATION-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT/locations/LOCATION/endpoints/ENDPOINT_ID:predict
> ```

Alternatively we can use [gcloud ai endpoints list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/endpoints/list) command.

```
$ LOCATION='us-central1'
$ gcloud ai endpoints list --region=${LOCATION} --uri
Using endpoint [https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/]
https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/335513839215/locations/us-central1/endpoints/5031620295400620032
```

We can check the available Vertex AI API service endpoint URL FQDN part in [Vertex AI API - Service: aiplatform.googleapis.com](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest#rest_endpoints)

```
https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://us-east1-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://us-east4-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://us-west1-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://us-west2-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://northamerica-northeast1-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://northamerica-northeast2-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://europe-west1-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://europe-west2-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://europe-west3-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://europe-west4-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://europe-west6-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://asia-east1-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://asia-east2-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://asia-northeast1-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://asia-northeast3-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://asia-south1-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://asia-southeast1-aiplatform.googleapis.com
https://australia-southeast1-aiplatform.googleapis.com
```

### Google API for Vertex endpoint prediction

The URL format above is based on the API definition [Method: projects.locations.endpoints.predict](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.endpoints/predict).

> ```
> POST https://{service-endpoint}/v1/{endpoint}:predict
> ```
>
> Where {service-endpoint} is one of the supported service endpoints.

---

## Authentication

GCP uses [OAuth 2.0 for authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) by default, and the Vertex AI endpoint authenticates the access with the OAuth 2.0 access token set in the HTTP Authorization header as a Bearer token.

RFC 6749 - The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework

```
     +--------+                               +---------------+
     |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ->|   Resource    |
     |        |                               |     Owner     |
     |        |<-(B)-- Authorization Grant ---|               |
     |        |                               +---------------+
     |        |
     |        |                               +---------------+
     |        |--(C)-- Authorization Grant -->| Authorization |
     | Client |                               |     Server    |
     |        |<-(D)----- Access Token -------|               |
     |        |                               +---------------+
     |        |
     |        |                               +---------------+
     |        |--(E)----- Access Token ------>|    Resource   |
     |        |                               |     Server    |
     |        |<-(F)--- Protected Resource ---|               |
     +--------+                               +---------------+
```

If we have gcloud command available e.g. inside a GCP environment, we can use the [ADC (Application Default Credentials)](https://google.aip.dev/auth/4110) to first get authenticated with `gcloud auth application-default login` and obtain the token using the `gloud auth print-access-token` command. Then the token can be specified to the HTTP header as in the Vertex AI documentation below.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
"https://LOCATION-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT/locations/LOCATION/endpoints/ENDPOINT_ID:predict"
```

---

## Request body format

- [Request body](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.endpoints/predict#request-body).

> ```
> {
>   "instances": [
>     value
>   ],
>   "parameters": value
> }
> ```

The actual value to set depends on the frameworks. See [Get online predictions from custom-trained models- Format your input for online prediction](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-predictions-custom-models#formatting-prediction-input) if you are getting predictions from custom models.