# Using (Bearer) Api token on Gemini Pro version in Java

Tags: java, bearer-token, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini

### Question

How can I ask "Can you say hello?" to the Gemini Pro model in Java, using a (Bearer) API token as **only** means of authentication?

### Example

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75933132/7437143) contains an example that shows how one is able to use an API token to interact with the Vertex AI. For example, it shows how one can log on device `A` in using one's Google account and then use that authentication to obtain a (Bearer) API token. I **assume** this API token can then be used on device `B` to ask: "Can you say hello world?" to the Gemini Pro model of Google's Vertex AI, without login into one's Google account and password on device `B`.

Alternatively, one can directly ask an API token for the Gemini Pro model of Google's Vertex AI at: `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<your_project_name>`.  However, I have not yet found out how to use that API token in Java **only** code to ask the model: "Can you say hello world?".

### Note

For completeness I ensured I can use the Gemini Pro model with normal authentication, using [this](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/multimodal/send-chat-prompts-gemini) example:

```java
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.VertexAI;
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.api.GenerateContentResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.generativeai.preview.ChatSession;
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.generativeai.preview.GenerativeModel;
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.generativeai.preview.ResponseHandler;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ChatDiscussion {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
    String projectId = "your-google-cloud-project-id";
    String location = "us-central1";
    String modelName = "gemini-pro";

    chatDiscussion(projectId, location, modelName);
  }

  // Ask interrelated questions in a row using a ChatSession object.
  public static void chatDiscussion(String projectId, String location, String modelName)
      throws IOException {
    // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs
    // to be created once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
    try (VertexAI vertexAI = new VertexAI(projectId, location)) {
      GenerateContentResponse response;

      GenerativeModel model = new GenerativeModel(modelName, vertexAI);
      // Create a chat session to be used for interactive conversation.
      ChatSession chatSession = new ChatSession(model);

      response = chatSession.sendMessage("Hello.");
      System.out.println(ResponseHandler.getText(response));

      response = chatSession.sendMessage("What are all the colors in a rainbow?");
      System.out.println(ResponseHandler.getText(response));

      response = chatSession.sendMessage("Why does it appear when it rains?");
      System.out.println(ResponseHandler.getText(response));
      System.out.println("Chat Ended.");
    }
  }
}
```

The Bearer Api token can then be found using:

```bash
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

Comment: response body is null, what about response headers? specifically, what response code (error or ok)?

Comment: Thank you fro your question, I have looked up how to include the response headers and response code, included it in the code, and updated the output accordingly.

Comment: 404 is not found...that means your url's query string is incorrect...before a token can be verified the exact request target needs to be identified

Comment: Thank you for sharing your observations and interpretation. I assume the `endpointId` is not valid. I am looking for a way to combine code method of the [example](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/multimodal/send-chat-prompts-gemini) (2nd code) with the Bearer API token, as the 2nd code of the example does not need the `endpointId`.

Comment: You cannot use an API key as the HTTP `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN` header. The authorization is failing which will prevent you from accessing the endpoint. Some endpoints do not accept API keys. For those that do, you would specify a URL query parameter `key=REPLACE_WITH_API_KEY`. If you include a link to the API document page I can check for you.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation on why the chosen approach does not work. [This](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest) seems to be the Vertex AI API documentation. I have included an additional explicit clarification, aimed at conveying what I am working towards, with increased comprehensibility.

Comment: I meant the documentation page, not the group section. If you provide the actual link, then we don't have to spend time figuring out which API you are using. Your link is to a set of APIs.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you, I do not yet know which API documentation I should use to ask "`Hello world?`" to the Google Vertex AI with an API token, if/when I do find out, I will post it here.

Comment: How can you write code if you have not read the documentation for the API you are using? Perhaps you misunderstand what I am asking for. If you make it simple for someone to understand your question and problem, you will have a better chance of getting a good answer. As written, your question is a mess with too much information that does not matter and not enough details for what does matter. Show the code, a link to the API you are using, and error messages.

Comment: Thank you, I agree that the question was a mess, and that including my approach caused more confusion instead of progress. Accordingly, I removed my own code attempt, and simplified the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256915/discussion-between-a-t-and-john-hanley).

Comment: I found [this page](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/client-libraries) which may be what you are looking for. It explains how to generate a "service account key" and download it as a JSON file. Then you set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to point to it. When defined, the SDK uses it to authenticate. If I got it right, you should be able to just copy the file to another computer, define the environment variable and it will work.

Comment: @Olivier Thank you! If one can write a robust java code that sets that environment variable on Windows and Ubuntu, and is able to verify copying the `.json` file to a new computer indeed allows one to to ask: "Hello world" in a java MWE, it would answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

**Your Requirements**

> Using (Bearer) Api token on Gemini Pro version in Java.

> without login into one's Google account and password on device B.

**Summary**

You cannot use API Keys with the Vertex AI. You must switch the type of credentials or the API. The Vertex AI supports service accounts that do not require user logins.

**Recommendation**

I recommend that you switch to the [Google AI Gemini API](https://ai.google.dev/docs/gemini_api_overview) because of support for mobile devices and API Keys. Later you can switch the credential type from API Keys to [User OAuth](https://ai.google.dev/docs/oauth_quickstart) if private data needs to be managed.

**Notes**

There is no such item as an API token in Google Cloud. Using that wording will create confusion. See below for more details.

You mention device B without defining what type of device. I will assume a mobile device such as Android or iPhone. The Vertex AI is not designed for use on mobile devices and doing so will present security challenges.

**Details**

The Gemini service provides two APIs and corresponding SDKs:

- [Google AI Gemini API](https://ai.google.dev/docs/gemini_api_overview#android)
- [Google Cloud Vertex AI Gemini API](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/learn/overview)]

The first API is based on a simpler design and supports mobile devices.
The second API is more complex and feature rich. It is designed to integrate with Google Cloud IAM and other Google Cloud services. This [document](https://ai.google.dev/docs/migrate_to_cloud) has more details comparing the two APIs.

There are two types of credentials used by those APIs for authorization:

- API Keys
- OAuth Access Tokens

There are four types of credentials supported by Google Cloud:

- API Keys
- JWT Assertions
- OAuth Access Tokens
- OIDC Identity Tokens

JWT Assertions, OAuth, and OIDC tokens can be used for **Bearer** tokens. API Keys cannot be used as Bearer tokens in Google Cloud.

The **Google AI Gemini API** supports API Keys and [User OAuth Access Tokens](https://ai.google.dev/docs/oauth_quickstart). The **Google Cloud Vertex AI Gemini API** requires OAuth access tokens and does not support API Keys.

Your example code is using the **Google Cloud Vertex AI Gemini API** which does not support API Keys.

**You have two options:**

1. Continue using the Vertex SDK and switch to OAuth for authorization which supports user and service accounts.
2. Switch to the Google AI Gemini API. This [document](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/android_quickstart) provides details and example code in Java for Android. I am not aware of a Java SDK for backend (server) code. The [HTTP REST API](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/rest_quickstart) is easy to work with and can be easily written in Java.

**Generate Content Example**

The HTTP REST API includes a [curl example](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/rest_quickstart#text-only_input) that you can port to Java.

I have improved the documentation example.

```
curl https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-pro:generateContent \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'x-goog-api-key: MY_API_KEY' \
  -X POST \
  -d '{
        "contents": [{
          "parts":[{
            "text": "Write a story about a magic backpack."
          }]
         }]
       }'
```

**Suggestion**

Do not include the API Key as part of the HTTP request query parameter. That can be a security vulnerability in some environments. Instead, pass the API Key using the HTTP header **x-goog-api-key**. Example:

```
x-goog-api-key: MY_API_KEY
```