# Gemini Ai through Vertex AI Integration: Payment and Query Limits for Chatbot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chat, integration, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini

Is **Gemini AI through Vertex AI** (Google Cloud/Vertex AI) currently available on a **pay-as-you-go** basis, or are there **limitations** such as 60 queries per minute?
I need quick help as I want to implement it in my chatbot application, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Gemini service provides two APIs and corresponding SDKs:

- Google AI Gemini API
- Google Cloud Vertex AI Gemini API

The Google AI Gemini API has free API calls. This API is not part of Vertex AI and uses an API Key. Up to 60 QPM are free. [link](https://ai.google.dev/pricing)

The Google Cloud Vertex AI Gemini API is a paid service.

[Pricing for Generative AI on Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/pricing)

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78022183/8016720) for more information on the two APIs.